# Difficulty in using subplots to shows multiple boxplots side-by-side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using the heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv dataset, you can find it here: https://www.kaggle.com/abdallahwagih/heart-failure-clinical-records-dataset-eda
Now I created two subsets of the initial dataframe using the code below:

```
group1 = a[(a["sex"] == 1) & (a["diabetes"] == 1) & (a["high_blood_pressure"] == 0)]group1.head()

group2 = a[(a["sex"] == 1) & (a["diabetes"] == 1) & (a["high_blood_pressure"] == 1)]group2.head()
```

I want the resulting boxplots for each of them to show up side by side as an output
I have plotted them individually by using the code below:

```
sns.boxplot(x = group1['age'], y = group1['creatinine_phosphokinase'])
sns.boxplot(x = group2['age'], y = group2['creatinine_phosphokinase'])
```

So I have been going around looking at subplots and subplot2grid and all that and this is what I have come up with so far

```
x1 = group1['age']
y1 = group1['creatinine_phosphokinase']
x2 = group2['age']
y2 = group2['creatinine_phosphokinase']
figure, axis = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axis[0, 0].plot(x1, y1)
```

I get hit with this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-126627fbbb24> in <module>
----> 1 axis[0, 0].plot(x1, y1)
      2 #axis[1, 0].plot(x2, y2)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I do not understand this error so any help will be appreciated.

I have also tried this:

```
plot1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0), colspan=2)
plot2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 2), rowspan=3, colspan=2)
plot2.plot(x1, y1)
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-f3ee75fcd504> in <module>
----> 1 plot2.plot('x1', 'y1')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1741         """
   1742         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1743         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1744         for line in lines:
   1745             self.add_line(line)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    271                 this += args[0],
    272                 args = args[1:]
--> 273             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    274 
    275     def get_next_color(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    394             self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
    395         if self.axes.yaxis is not None:
--> 396             self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    397 
    398         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in update_units(self, data)
   1464         neednew = self.converter != converter
   1465         self.converter = converter
-> 1466         default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1467         if default is not None and self.units is None:
   1468             self.set_units(default)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py in default_units(data, axis)
    105         # the conversion call stack is default_units -> axis_info -> convert
    106         if axis.units is None:
--> 107             axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
    108         else:
    109             axis.units.update(data)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in set_units(self, u)
   1539         self.units = u
   1540         self._update_axisinfo()
-> 1541         self.callbacks.process('units')
   1542         self.callbacks.process('units finalize')
   1543         self.stale = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in process(self, s, *args, **kwargs)
    227                 except Exception as exc:
    228                     if self.exception_handler is not None:
--> 229                         self.exception_handler(exc)
    230                     else:
    231                         raise

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in _exception_printer(exc)
     79 def _exception_printer(exc):
     80     if _get_running_interactive_framework() in ["headless", None]:
---> 81         raise exc
     82     else:
     83         traceback.print_exc()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in process(self, s, *args, **kwargs)
    222             if func is not None:
    223                 try:
--> 224                     func(*args, **kwargs)
    225                 # this does not capture KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit,
    226                 # and GeneratorExit

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in recache_always(self)
    646 
    647     def recache_always(self):
--> 648         self.recache(always=True)
    649 
    650     def recache(self, always=False):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in recache(self, always)
    651         if always or self._invalidx:
    652             xconv = self.convert_xunits(self._xorig)
--> 653             x = _to_unmasked_float_array(xconv).ravel()
    654         else:
    655             x = self._x

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in _to_unmasked_float_array(x)
   1287         return np.ma.asarray(x, float).filled(np.nan)
   1288     else:
-> 1289         return np.asarray(x, float)
   1290 
   1291 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order, like)
    100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, like=like)
    101 
--> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    103 
    104 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

Comment: Change `axis[0, 0]` to `axis[0]`. `axis` is one-dimensional.

Comment: Please read [Creating multiple subplots using plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#creating-multiple-subplots-using-plt-subplots) to understand that `axis` is an axis object, a one-dimensional array containing axes objects, or a two-dimensional array containing axes objects depending on the initiated layout.

Comment: Note that you can use `squeeze=False` (as in `fig, axs = plt.subplots(..., squeeze=False)`) to always have a 2D array of `axs`.

Comment: I did that and now its giving me this error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `axis[0, 0]` to `axis[0]` will fix the issue.

```
axis[0].plot(x1, y1)
axis[1].plot(x2, y2)
```

If you only want to plot those boxplots side by side then:

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(25, 8))
sns.boxplot(x = group1['age'], y = group1['creatinine_phosphokinase'], ax=ax[0])
sns.boxplot(x = group2['age'], y = group2['creatinine_phosphokinase'], ax=ax[1])
fig.show()
```

this should work

Comment: I did that and now its giving me this error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Comment: Check my updated answer once. I've tested it, it is working fine